# How to convert an string to a Char(20) sql datatype

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to insert a string into a `char(20)` column in my SQL Server database.

I set the string to be equal to a value and then add it to a parameter

```
thisstring = "1914"
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@code", thisstring)
```

However every time I try it ends up looking like this in the database

[image: picture]

I need it to look like the `1913, 000000, 000001` ones.

When I try to pad the string with spaces

```
thisstring= thisstring.PadLeft(20, " ")
```

or

```
thisstring = "     " & thisstring
```

I am getting

> String or binary data would be truncated

even if the field wasn't 20 characters total

What am I doing wrong?

Edit*** here is the column in SQL Server

[http://imgur.com/BbV6VQv](https://imgur.com/BbV6VQv)

Comment: what is the SQL or stored procedure call with `cmd`, i.e. `cmd.CommandText`?

Comment: thisstring= thisstring.PadLeft(20, " ") should have worked.  Can you double check the parameter definition.  This could be different than the table definition.

Comment: cmd = New SqlCommand(strSQL, conn)  and the execute is cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not absolutely sure, but I think the problem lies in the AddWithValue.
While convenient this method doesn't allow to specify the exact datatype to pass to the database engine and neither the size of the parameter. It pass always an nvarchar parameter for a C# UNICODE string.

I think you should try with the standard syntax used to build a parameter

```
Dim p = new SqlParameter("@code", SqlDbType.Char, 20)
p.Value = thisstring.PadLeft(20, " ")
```

[See this very interesting article on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee236412.aspx)